# How to aggregate multiple rows into one in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Suppose you have a de-normalized schema with multiple rows like below:

```
   uuid    |    property    |    value   
------------------------------------------
  abc      |   first_name   |  John
  abc      |   last_name    |  Connor
  abc      |   age          |  26
...
```

The same set of properties for all rows, not necessarily sorted. **How to create a table such as using BigQuery** (i.e. no client):

Table user_properties:

```
   uuid    |    first_name  |    last_name   |    age
 --------------------------------------------------------
  abc      |   John         |    Connor      |    26
```

In traditional SQL there is the "STUFF" keyword for this purpose.

It would be easier if I could at least **get the results ORDERED by uuid** so the client would not need to load the whole table (4GB) to sort -- it would be possible to hydrate each entity by scanning sequentially the rows with same uuid. However, a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM user_properties ORDER BY uuid;
```

exceeds the available resources in BigQuery (using allowLargeResults forbids ORDER BY). It almost seems like I cannot sort a large table (4GB) in BigQuery unless I subscribe to a high end machine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  uuid,
  MAX(IF(property = 'first_name', value, NULL)) AS first_name,
  MAX(IF(property = 'last_name', value, NULL)) AS last_name,
  MAX(IF(property = 'age', value, NULL)) AS age
FROM user_properties
GROUP BY uuid
```

> Another option - no GROUP'ing involved

```
SELECT uuid, first_name, last_name, age  
FROM (
  SELECT 
    uuid,
    LEAD(value, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY uuid ORDER BY property) AS first_name,
    LEAD(value, 2) OVER(PARTITION BY uuid ORDER BY property) AS last_name,
    value AS age,
    property = 'age' AS anchor
  FROM user_properties
)
HAVING anchor
```

Comment: I got `SELECT list expression references column flow_timestamp which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [1:8]` when I tried to use the same technic in my query.   `SELECT 
flow_timestamp,
MAX(IF(channel_properties.key = 'number_of_digits', channel_properties.value, NULL)) AS number_of_digits
FROM my_table
, unnest(timeseries.channel_properties) as channel_properties`Is is because channel_properties is a nested field?

Comment: @Yang - yes. post you issue as new question and I will follow up with answer

Comment: thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58666596/bigquery-pivoting-with-nested-field

Comment: sure, will check it :o)