# bigquery pivoting with nested field

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a bigquery table with schema:

[image]

I would like to have this result:

```
flow_timestamp, channel_name, number_of_digits
2019-10-31 15:31:15, channel_name_1, 3,
2019-10-31 15:31:15, channel_name_2, 4,
:
:
```

My query: `SELECT flow_timestamp, timeseries.channel_name, MAX(IF(channel_properties.key = 'number_of_digits', channel_properties.value, NULL)) AS number_of_digits FROM my_table , unnest(timeseries.channel_properties) as channel_properties`

I have tried same technic shown here, 
[How to aggregate multiple rows into one in BigQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35789156/how-to-aggregate-multiple-rows-into-one-in-bigquery#)

but got an error `SELECT list expression references column flow_timestamp which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [1:8]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  flow_timestamp, 
  timeseries.channel_name, 
  ( SELECT MAX(IF(channel_properties.key = 'number_of_digits', channel_properties.value, NULL)) 
    FROM UNNEST(timeseries.channel_properties) AS channel_properties
  ) AS number_of_digits 
FROM my_table
```

Comment: Hi thanks. In real, my table has even more nested fields. I have a field that has 5 layers. I'm wondering if that is a good practice, because it makes the query very complicated. But on the other hand, it avoids to store repeated information.

Comment: post new question with all relevant details so we will be able to answer it

Comment: Okay, thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58684318/pivot-multi-level-nested-fields-in-bigquery